# Circular dependent: :destroy in ActiveRecord possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, dependent-destroy

Is it safe to have circular `dependent: :destroy` options in ActiveRecord models?

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, dependent: :destroy
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student, dependent: :destroy
end
```

If I delete a `user`, it should delete the associated `student`. And vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  AR will just issue delete queries for each entity within a single transaction.  So, let's say a user has 2 students (a and b).  If you delete student a, AR will delete student a, causing a delete of user, causing a delete of student b, causing a final duplicate delete of user.  The duplicate delete (aside from a small performance hit), will not cause any sort of error.  The reverse, deleting the user will also work fine.

Comment: Is this standard practice in Rails/ActiveRecord?